# add a parameter in url(angularjs)

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-1.6

I would like to be able to keep the parameter it in url after the click.

When I'm on the offline page I have this url:

> http://localhost:3000/feliway-coupon?src_org=166

And I would like to have the same one once connected. However, the parameters do not remain. And that gives this once connected :

> http://localhost:3000/feliway-coupon

And I would just like this parameter (`src_org=166`) to remain

HTML:

```
<button ng-click="$ctrl.onConnect()">connect</button>
```

JS:

```
onConnect() {
  const search = this.$location.search().src_org

  if (search === '166') {
    this.$location.state().search('src_org', '166')
  }
}
```

I wanted to know if $location could solve this problem? Or by another method  but without using ui-router or ng-route.

Comment: why don't you just pass it as a string to the url ?

Comment: which is? `this.$location.state() + 'src_org=166'`. I don't know how to do this, but does it look like this?

Comment: yes, pretty much

Comment: did it work? let me know

Comment: No, it still doesn't work, but I'm trying and I hope it will work out after a while

Comment: I think you may have forgotten the question mark try `?src_org=166` instead of `src_org=166`

Comment: Thank you very much for your help I succeeded :)

Comment: can I post it as an answer so you can accept it?

Comment: In the end, that wasn't the answer, but it doesn't matter. It still helped me out, so no worries I'll validate your answer.

Comment: well if you found the answer yourself, feel free to post it in your question. I'm also curious on how you solved the problem.